# Prevent Beamer Background On One Slide

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I wanted to make a background on each of my slides on a Beamer presentation, and this link did exactly what I needed:
[Background image in beamer slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/background-image-in-beamer-slides)
And this works perfectly, except for the first slide. I only want my background for my slides with content, but not the Title slide. Does anyone know if there is a way to disable the `setbeamertemplate{background}` for the first slide only? Thank you

Comment: Just put `\setbeamertemplate{background}{<settings>}` after the first slide. Not an elegant solution, sorry. Look also at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142989/231952

Comment: @Ivan This worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information what you after are very general, so there is only one example (based on answer on question [creating-title-page-in-latex-beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399773/creating-title-page-in-latex-beamer)) how you can do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\author{K}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain] % exception of frame style
    \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame with content}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```